# Zip File with PPMD Compression, Programmatically Unzip

Tags: python, linux, compression, zip

I have a Linux Python script that needs to unzip some zip files.  I was using the zipfile module.  On a few of these files I'm getting:

```
BadZipfile: Unsupported compression method 98 for file
```

Searching around it seems these files are using [Method 98 PPMD compression](http://www.winzip.com/comp_info.htm).  I figured if python couldn't do it, I'd make a hack system call to unzip 6.0 and be done with it.  This errors:

```
skipping: fileName `PPMd' method not supported
```

I've tried 7zip:

```
Extracting  fileName     Unsupported Method
```

I thought I hit pay-dirt with a command line utility ppmd, but:

```
Fast PPMII compressor for textual data, variant I, Nov  6 2009
Segmentation fault
```

Anything else I can try?  WinZip in windows has no problem with these files, but I need to do this in Linux.

Comment: command line `ppmd` was the right choice. how exactly did you run it ?

Comment: That's pretty unusual. You should check with the source to see if they really did compress with ppmd, or if you have a corrupted zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You can find https://pypi.org/project/zipfile39/ that support zip with PPMd

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the p7zip (binary)?

It seems to support the PPMD compression format.

Some PPMd switches:  -mmem=24b, -mmem=24k, -mmem=24m, -mo=2, and -mo=32

Comment: @OldTroll: thanks, but I just can not p7zip to do this and according to their FAQ (http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html#user_faq), they don't  support WinZip's PPMD.

Answer (score 0):

7-zip supports zip/ppmd from 9.11 beta (2010-03-15) according to https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt .

Oh, you are mentioning Python. Yes zipfile39 module should be helpful as @hiroshi miura says. You can also use https://pypi.org/project/zipfile-ppmd/.