# Python unzip large file - NotImplementedError: compression type 98

Tags: python, unzip, zip

I am using following Python code to unzip the files

```
import zipfile
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(input_file_path)
zfile.extractall(output_path)
```

However, when I try to unzip a larger file. It throws the following error.

> NotImplementedError: compression type 98 (ppmd)

How should I fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690993/zip-file-with-ppmd-compression-programmatically-unzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `zipfile` module does not support PPMd compression--see [issue 14366](http://bugs.python.org/issue14366) (emphasis added):

> I think we should add the ability to register new codecs. **Support for PPMd, jpeg and WavPack is unlikely to emerge in the Python in the foreseeable future,** but users of third-party libraries (such as PIL), will use the new codecs as needed.

There are only two options:

- Use an external zip program from Python, and the `subprocess` module.  The `p7zip` program would do the job nicely.
- Modify Python to add PPMd support to the `zipfile` module.

Keep in mind that PPMd is an extremely uncommon codec to use, so most programs (including regular `unzip`) do not support it at all.

Comment: thank you @Dietrich Epp, I need to run the Python code in a Unix terminal server so I can only use the 2nd solution that you suggested. Do you know any resources that would help me to add PPMd support?

Comment: @merimini: What are you talking about?  `subprocess` works fine from the terminal.